# Stream Buffer crashes in qdv.dll Win7

Tags: c++, stream, directshow

I have this code for streaming to/from a stream buffer. I've left all error checking out to make the code easier to read and see what I'm doing.

```
ICaptureGraphBuilder2*  pCaptureGraphBuilder = nullptr;

IGraphBuilder*          pGraphCapture = nullptr;
IMediaControl*          pControlCapture = nullptr;

IGraphBuilder*          pGraphStream = nullptr;
IMediaControl*          pControlStream = nullptr;

IBaseFilter*            pFilterVideoIn = nullptr;
IBaseFilter*            pFilterDVEncode = nullptr;

IBaseFilter*            pFilterBufferCapture = nullptr;
IBaseFilter*            pFilterBufferStream = nullptr;

// streams
IStreamBufferSink2*     pBufferCapture = nullptr;
IStreamBufferSource*    pBufferStream = nullptr;

// This sets up the streaming capture
HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CaptureGraphBuilder2,nullptr,CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,IID_PPV_ARGS(&pCaptureGraphBuilder));

hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FilterGraph,nullptr,CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,IID_PPV_ARGS(&pGraphCapture));
hr = pCaptureGraphBuilder->SetFiltergraph(pGraphCapture);
hr = pGraphCapture->QueryInterface(IID_IMediaControl,(VOID**)&pControlCapture);

hr = EnumClassForFilterName(CLSID_VideoInputDeviceCategory,TEXT_CAPTUREDEVICE,&pFilterVideoIn); // This functions creates an instance of the capture device
hr = pGraphCapture->AddFilter(pFilterVideoIn,L"VideoIn");

hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_DVVideoEnc,nullptr,CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,IID_PPV_ARGS(&pFilterDVEncode));
hr = pGraphCapture->AddFilter(pFilterDVEncode,L"DVEncoder");

hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_StreamBufferSink,nullptr,CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,IID_PPV_ARGS(&pBufferCapture));
hr = pBufferCapture->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&pFilterBufferCapture));
hr = pGraphCapture->AddFilter(pFilterBufferCapture,L"BufferSink");

hr = pCaptureGraphBuilder->RenderStream(&PIN_CATEGORY_CAPTURE,&MEDIATYPE_Video,pFilterVideoIn,pFilterDVEncode,pFilterBufferCapture);

hr = pBufferCapture->LockProfile(L"C:\\save.tmp");

// now work on the stream in
hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FilterGraph,nullptr,CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,IID_PPV_ARGS(&pGraphStream));
hr = pGraphStream->QueryInterface(IID_IMediaControl,(VOID**)&pControlStream);

hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_StreamBufferSource,nullptr,CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,IID_PPV_ARGS(&pBufferStream));
hr = pBufferStream->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&pFilterBufferStream));
hr = pGraphStream->AddFilter(pFilterBufferStream,L"StreamBufferSource");

hr = pBufferStream->SetStreamSink(pBufferCapture);

IEnumPins* pEnumPins = nullptr;
IPin* pPin = nullptr;
hr = pFilterBufferStream->EnumPins(&pEnumPins);
while(pEnumPins->Next(1,&pPin,nullptr) == S_OK){
    hr = pGraphStream->Render(pPin);
    pPin->Release();
}

// Which filters are really in the graph

// capture graph
OutputDebugString(L"-----------------------\n");
OutputDebugString(L"StreamIn Graph Filters\n");
OutputDebugString(L"\n");

IEnumFilters* pFilterEnum = nullptr;
IBaseFilter* pFilter = nullptr;
WCHAR name[256] = {0};
hr = pGraphCapture->EnumFilters(&pFilterEnum);
while(pFilterEnum->Next(1,&pFilter,nullptr) == S_OK){
    FILTER_INFO fi={0};
    pFilter->QueryFilterInfo(&fi);
    StringCchPrintf(name,255,L"%s\n",fi.achName);
    OutputDebugString(name);

    fi.pGraph->Release();
    pFilter->Release();
}
OutputDebugString(L"-----------------------\n");

// stream graph
OutputDebugString(L"-----------------------\n");
OutputDebugString(L"StreamSource Graph Filters\n");
OutputDebugString(L"\n");

pFilterEnum = nullptr;
pFilter = nullptr;
hr = pGraphStream->EnumFilters(&pFilterEnum);
while(pFilterEnum->Next(1,&pFilter,nullptr) == S_OK){
    FILTER_INFO fi={0};
    pFilter->QueryFilterInfo(&fi);
    WCHAR name[256]={0};
    StringCchPrintf(name,256,L"%s\n",fi.achName);
    OutputDebugString(name);

    fi.pGraph->Release();
    pFilter->Release();
}
OutputDebugString(L"-----------------------\n");

hr = pControlCapture->Run();
hr = pControlStream->Run();

[SNIP]
```

and it crashes as soon as the 2nd graph starts to run with

```
First-chance exception at 0x000007fef3ce42e0 (qdv.dll) in StreamBuffer.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000000001c5.
Unhandled exception at 0x000007fef3ce42e0 (qdv.dll) in StreamBuffer.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000000001c5.
```

Which is telling me that something is not happy inside qdv.dll. So I downloaded the debug symbols to help diagnose whats really happening.

In the call stack I get

```
qdv.dll!CDVVideoCodec::Receive()  + 0x220 bytes 
qdv.dll!CTransformInputPin::Receive()  + 0x4c bytes 
qdv.dll!CBaseInputPin::ReceiveMultiple()  + 0x49 bytes  
sbe.dll!COutputQueue::ThreadProc()  + 0xca bytes    
sbe.dll!COutputQueue::InitialThreadProc()  + 0x1c bytes 
kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk()  + 0xd bytes 
ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()  + 0x21 bytes
```

This tells me that perhaps I haven't supplied enough information in one of the graphs for DVEncoder. I've tried various settings for the codec but nothing works and I get the same crash in the same place with the same error.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: The problem looks related to DV filter (decoder?) which is likely to crash on some kind of unexpected data. DV implementation is terrible, it's hard to figure out what is wrong exactly.

Comment: Hiya, Indeed it certainly looks like the problem is in the decoder, and as you suggest, probably by some unexpected data and not handling the data correctly, and is simply crashing rather giving a decent error report. My thoughts are that it's the DVEncoder that would be issuing that data, which if isn't setup correctly will crash the decoder?

Do you have any suggestions as the best way to handle this? I like the idea of the streaming solution.

Comment: The best I can think of is finding this data exactly, that crashes DV filter, then update it respectively to avoid crashing. This might be tricky but DV filter seems to be requiring this.

Comment: Yes, I think I'll play with this over the weekend. Thankyou for your time.